# Java File is disappearing from the path /tmp/hsperfdata_*username*/

Tags: java, file, jboss

This is very confusing problem.

We have a Java-application (Java8 and running on JBoss 6.4) that is looping a certain amount of objects and writing some rows to a File on each round.

On each round we check did we receive the File object as a parameter and if we did not, we create a new object and create a physical file:

```
if (file == null){
   File file = new File(filename);
   try{
        file.createNewFile();
   } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
```

So the idea is that the file get's created only once and after that the step is skipped and we proceed straight to writing. The variable filename is not a path, it's just a file name with no path so the file gets created to a path jboss_root/tmp/hsperfdata_*username*/

edit1. I'll add here also the methods used from writing if they happen to make relevance:

```
fw = new FileWriter(indeksiFile, true); // append = true
bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
out = new PrintWriter(bw);
.
.
out.println(..)
.
.
out.flush();
out.close(); // this flushes as well -> line above is useless
```

So now the problem is that occasionally, quite rarely thou, the physical file disappears from the path in the middle of the process. The java-object reference is never lost, but is seems that the object itself disappears because the code automatically creates the file again to the same path and keeps on writing stuff to it. This would not happen if the condition file == null would not evaluate to true. The effect is obviously that we loose the rows which were written to the previous file. Java application does not notice any errors and keeps on working.

So, I would have three questions which are strongly related for which I was not able to find answer from google.

1. If we call method File.CreateNewFile(), is the resulting file a permanent file in the filesystem or some JVM-proxy-file?
2. If it's permanent file, do you have any idea why it's disappearing? The default behavior in our case is that at some point the file is always deleted from the path. My guess is that same mechanism is deleting the file too early. I just dunno how to control that mechanism.
3. My best guess is that this is related to this path jboss_root/tmp/hsperfdata_*username*/ which is some temp-data folder created by the JVM and probably there is some default behavior that cleans the path. Am I even close?

Help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`File.createNewFile` I never used in my code: it is not needed.
When afterwards actually writing to the file, it probaby creates it anew, or appends.
In every case there is a race on the file system. Also as these are not atomic actions,
you might end up with something unstable.

So you want to write to a file, either appending on an existing file, or creating it.
For UTF-8 text:

```
Path path = Paths.get(filename);
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
        Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND),
            false)) {
    out.println("Killroy was here");
}
```

---

***After comment***
Honestly as you are interested in the cause, it is hard to say. An application restart or I/O (?) exceptions one would find in the logs. Add logging to a specific log for appending to the files, and a (logged) periodic check for those files' existence.

---

***Safe-guard***
Here we are doing repeated physical access to the file system.

To prevent appending to a file twice at the same time (of which I would expect an exception), one can make a critical section in some form.

```
// For 16 semaphores:
final int semaphoreCount = 16;
final int semaphoreMask = 0xF;
Semaphore[] semaphores = new Semaphore[semaphoreCount];
for (int i = 0; i < semaphores.length; ++i) {
    semaphores[i] = new Semaphore(1, true); // FIFO
}

int hash = filename.hashcode() & semaphoreMask ; // toLowerCase on Windows
Semaphore semaphore = semaphores[hash];
try {
    semaphore.aquire();
    ... append
} finally {
    semaphore.release();
}
```

File locks would have been a more technical solution, which I would not like to propose.

The best solution, you perhaps already have, would be to *queue messages per file*.

Comment: I'm sure this is probably very close to be a solution to fix the issue but this does not help me to understand the phenomenon observed with current solution. As a background info, the current solution is already in prod and it does work for like 90% of the time (which for sure it not enough). I'd really like to know what mechanism is now responsible for making the file disappear.

Comment: Data may disappear because of createNewFile, as atomicity is not guaranteed. The same thing, when the same file is appended at the same time. One measure I'll add to the answer.

Comment: "An application restart or I/O (?) exceptions one would find in the logs. Add logging to a specific log for appending to the files, and a (logged) periodic check for those files' existence." Application does not notice a thing, no I/O exception. And yeah we did a verification that the file is first created, then it disappears and then it's created again by logging a periodic check.
Remember that createNewFile (at least should) be called only once. So what would be the mechanism causing the file which it created to be gone later on? What do you mean by appended at the same time, by who?

Comment: I meant concurrency, if more than one thread would do the same. Or in a rare case when the application is restarted (doing twice a createNewFile). The most likely cause would be a second createNewFile on the _same_ file name - a duplicate file name created somehow. Like with a time pattern hhmmss instead of HHmmss; the first is a twelve hour, repeating, pattern. Also System.currentMillis may not advance its long result. Simply said: _I have no idea._